# Remove git: 'credential-manager' is not a git command. From Mac

Tags: git, macos

I ran the following on Git:

`git config --global credential.helper manager`

And now when doing a git push I get the error

`git: 'credential-manager' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

How can I remove this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've specified the credential helper `manager`, which is not available on macOS, which is why you're seeing this message.  Most macOS distributions of Git default to `osxkeychain`, which is the right choice.

To fix this, you can run this:

```
$ git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

If you then run `git config credential.helper`, you can see if there's a setting for `osxkeychain`, and if not, add one with a variant of your original command.